# How to replace values in a Pandas Dataframe on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I defined a list of values that I am searching for in a column of a dataframe and want to replace all values in that df that match.

```
  First_name
0        Jon
1       Bill
2       Bill



 names = {'First_name': ['Jon','Bill', 'Bill']}
    name_list = ['Bill']
    df = DataFrame(names,columns=['First_name'])
    df.loc[df['First_name'].apply(str) in name_list] = 'Killed'
```

Should result in

```
  First_name
0        Jon
1       Killed
2       Killed
```

but I'm getting an error

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not Series

Not too sure why, since I am applying (str) to the left operand

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
name_list = ['Bill']
df.loc[df['First_name'].isin(name_list), 'First_name'] = 'Killed'
```

Comment: .isin() did the trick, also sorry I forgot to include the brackets! Thanks